# Php header 301 redirect still let google to index content but now from newly redirected domain

Tags: redirects, php, 301-redirect

I've redirect my oldsite.tld site via PHP header like this.

```
<?php 
$url_sufix = "blabla";
header("Location: http://www.newsite.tld/".$url_sufix, true, 301);
exit;
```

After 3 mo I still can find fresh indexed content on google for oldsite.tld, with content and url_sufix from newsite.tld What am I doing wrong?

I'm not sure my code is doing it is supposed to, because with `site:oldsite.tld` and checking a date of cached content shows me that content is fresh from newly redirected newsite.tld.

This is something which should not happen. I'm loosing my positions because double content.
~200k indexed pages is affected..
First I was thinking that I have wrong (outdated code), but now not sure.

Comment: For a start you are redirecting to an HTTP (not https) site.   I imagine Google would take that as an indication you are not serious.  The duplicate content penalty is largely a myth (although Google will likely prefer one version over the other).  The question is why is does fresh content even exist on the old URL?

Comment: Dont ask me why I put http and not https, when you come on site its redirects you to https. I will change it definitely, but anyway why content is still there?

Comment: Have you tried the old url yourself ?  Does it raise an error or does it serve a page?